# Op amps with 1000 gain and 10 volt out

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

I've been looking for a part that I can boost a 10 mV signal to a 10 volt signal
using a single op amp, so far most of the op amps I've found only meet the gain requirements, but cannot output 10 volts.

Answer (score 1):

There are many op-amps that can put out 10V.  The LM321 is just one example. If you go on any of the semiconductor manufacturers' websites you can search for them parametrically.

Boosting a 100mV signal to 10V only requires a gain of 100, not 1000.  Be careful of bandwidth and especially slew rate limitations of the amplifier. (Depending on the frequency of your input signal, which is not stated.)

Comment: Slew rate I understand as the rate at which the output can change (basically a frequency maximum?), but what can be said about the bandwidth? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @sherrellbc Both slew rate and bandwidth limit the maximum frequency you can pass through the amplifier, but for different reasons.  The 3dB bandwith is a small-signal parameter and tells you the frequency at which your signal has "rolled off" by 3dB.  For large signals, the slew rate might start to distort your signal well before the 3dB bandwidth.  The slew rate is the maximum rate of change of the output due to the finite amount of current available to charge and discharge the internal compensation cap.

Comment: I understood everything you said until "internal compensation cap". What does this capacitor do and where could I find some more information about it? Also, is it as simple as increasing this charging current to increase slew-rate?

Comment: @sherrellbc The compensation cap provides the dominant pole in the op amp's open loop frequency response.  If you look at the open loop gain plot in the data sheet you will see a flat gain out to some relatively low frequency, at which point the gain starts to roll off at 20dB/decade.  That's the result of the compensation cap and it guarantees that the op amp will be stable under most closed loop conditions.  Increasing the charging current will certainly increase the slew rate, but it's set internally in the IC, and not typically adjustable by the user.

Comment: @sherrellbc If you Google "dominant pole compensation" you'll find a lot more information about this subject.

Comment: Ah, so the fact that the gain is stable under open-loop conditions (due to the compensation cap) lends itself as testament to the closed-loop conditions? Thank you for the suggested read.

Answer (score 1):

0.1 to 10V is a closed-loop gain of 100, not 1000.

If you want 1% accuracy you'll need an open loop gain of 100 x 100 or 10,000.

Just about any op-amp that can operate from (say) -5V / + 15V will allow a 0-10V output. You need to be more specific. An LM324 is about the cheapest at about 2 cents per amplifier.